# Addition law for elliptic curves of the form $x^2y^2+a(x+y)+b=0$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, elliptic-curves

Did anybody consider addition law for elliptic curves of the form $$x^2y^2+a(x+y)+b=0\,?$$ Does this form have any specific name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was done by [Euler](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/pages/E251.html) . Here you can see [original text](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/docs/originals/E251.pdf) and [english tranclation.](http://home.sandiego.edu/~langton/eell.pdf) $\smile$

Now it is known as **Euler-Chasles correspondence.**